# Are there any anime that play out from a oranyan protagonist's point-of-view?

Tags: tropes

There are anime which I have already watched that narrates based on the male protagonist's point-of-view (not an oranyan). For example is [Ano Hana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anohana%3a_The_Flower_We_Saw_That_Day), [Clannad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clannad_After_Story#Anime_series), etc. And a lot more anime with main tsundere female protagonist's point-of-view.

I'm looking for another example of anime (plot more inclined in romance) where the narration is inclined with a main **oranyan ("male tsundere") male protagonist's point-of-view** (since I think they are rare, or I just haven't watched that much anime series), not with the point-of-view of the female character who's in love with an oranyan male protagonist. Is there another example of this kind of anime (well, aside from [Sora no Manimani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sora_no_Manimani) if I'm correct that Saku was kind of oranyan)?

Comment: It's not an anime, but in Sadamoto's *Neon Genesis Evangelion* manga, Shinji is borderline tsundere.

Comment: @xjshiya could you be a bit more specific? Your question currently is a bit vague and not well scoped. Please consult [this meta](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/348/63) for the criteria list questions such as this one.

Comment: @Krazer, just an example of an anime where the protagonist is male and a tsundere. Tsundere characters are more inclined to female characters as I noticed.

Comment: Reasonably scoped? Debatable. Vague? Not at all. 
1. Male 2. Protagonist 3. Tsundere. What is vague?

Comment: The meaning of "tsundere," for typically for females, and "oranyan," typically for males, might not  be immediately apparent to some. Typically male "oranyan" characters vary greatly over the course of the series, compared to female "tsundere" characters, so they are sometimes hard to identify these characteristics (Naoki Irie vs. Yuu Matsuura) if you haven't watch or read lot of anime and manga. So I think it's best to define the reasonable set of criteria when asking these types of list questions so we don't alienate potential new and novice users want to try answering questions like these.

Comment: The definition of Tsundere is very clear from the Wikipedia link he posted. If someone wants to answer the question, they should at least know how to apply the given definition. It is also not necessary that every question asked here should be answerable by everyone. If someone does not understand the question, they can answer some other question which they do understand, while someone else who understands the question will answer this one. We cannot bring down the level of questions just so that everyone can have a shot at it.

Comment: I don't agree that the definition of tsundere is objective, whether we are talking about males or females. There are indisputable cases, but there are also many which are far from obvious. Where does Hitagi from Bakemonogatari fall? Or Revy from Black Lagoon, Kyouko from Madoka, ChiChi from Dragon Ball, or Minatsu from Seitokai no Ichizon? All display some qualities of a tsundere character, while also a lot of qualities atypical for tsunderes. That's sort of besides the point though, since I expect a complete list would have over a hundred entries, which is not reasonably scoped by any means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head, there's **Nodame Cantabile**'s Chiaki is the main character and central POV character of the series. He narrates and often has the "internal" voice when he interacts with other people. He starts by being cold to Nodame then turns warm to her.

Although it's not from his POV, Li Syaoran from **Card Captor Sakura** (not the Syaoran from **Tsubasa Chronicles**) can be considered oranyan, by his treatment of Sakura.

Oh, and Naoki Irie from **Itazura na Kiss**, too.

Comment: All the while I though this anime evolves around Nodame's point-of-view (because of the title). I'll check it out.

Comment: @xjshiya it starts with Chiaki, at least the first season. Later seasons of it is more focused on them as a pair.

Comment: Why are the last two series included in this answer if the series is not even from their POV?

Comment: @atlantiza because this question was merged with another and the original question didn't ask for a POV